# After opening popup, How do I redirect parent page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, redirect

In ASP.net and C# - in my pageLoad event, I'm clicking a button that has code written to get an SSO link, and then using the RegisterStartUpScript to add a window.open with the link to the SSO in it.

After the SSO opens and loads, I want to redirect the page with the pageLoad event to another page.

In the code below, autoOpenSSO and redirectUser are settings that are loaded in an admin UI.

The issue: When autoOpenSSO is true and I have the redirectUser set to false, the popup opens with no issue, but when I set the redirect to true, the popup does not open, and the page redirects back to my redirect address.

I want the popup to open and the page to redirect back to my redirect page, but feel like I'm missing something, and haven't had any luck searching.

My code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
       if (autoOpenSSO == true)
       {
           ccdetails_Click(this, null);
       }


     if (redirectUser == true)
       {               
        Response.Redirect(redirectAddress);               
       }


    }

    protected void ccdetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
        try
        {  
            string link = getSSOlink(ah1.InstitutionUserID, cardnumber).Trim();
            string s = "window.open('" + link + "','_blank', 'width=980,height=600,resizable=yes');";
            cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PopupScript", s, true);

        }

        catch (Exception se)
        {
           LogSystem.LogInfo(se.ToString());

        }
    }
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: You need to add an EventListener for the popup.

Comment: Thanks for the keywords @Anon.  I tried adding var popupWindow = window.open('" + link + "','_blank', 'width=980,height=600,resizable=yes'); if (popupWindow) { popupWindow.onload = function() {window.location.replace('" + redirectAddress +"') };}, but because it's cross domain, I don't think my JS can get the do the function when window.onLoad would fire.  I'm thinking of setting a timeout to fix it.

Comment: Well, for my needs, I just determined that I didn't need a listener or anything.  I just added the redirect language with my startup script instead of in the C#.  I'm going to make a setting that adds the script if desired, and if not, it will stay on the page and not redirect.  I'll add code later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was add another line of js to my register startup scrip that redirects to my desired page.  Modified code can be found below.  I have settings on my page that allow me to decide whether I want to auto open the SSO and auto redirect the user after the SSO opens, which is the purpose for the s=s+t section.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         

       if (autoOpenSSO == true)
       {
           ccdetails_Click(this, null);
       }

    }

    protected void ccdetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
        try
        {                
            string link = getSSOlink(ah1.InstitutionUserID, cardnumber).Trim();
            string s = "var popupWindow = window.open('" + link + "','_blank', 'width=980,height=600,resizable=yes');";
            string t = "window.location.replace('" + redirectAddress + "')";
            if (redirectUser == true)
            {
                s = s + t;
            }
            cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PopupScript", s, true);

        }

        catch (Exception se)
        {
            LogSystem.LogInfo("Access issue - " + se.ToString());

        }
    }
```